# Does Wubi format my C drive if I select C drive in 'installation drive'

Tags: installation, wubi, windows-7

I'm really excited to actually install Ubuntu on my computer but I would like a way that doesn't take up too much disk space and neither lets me have risks of mistakenly formatting / partitioning the system drive, and also with an easy to uninstall.

I found Wubi.

But the official Wubi Guide doesn't make it clear.

When this screen appears (the picture is from the Wubi Guide)

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/WubiGuide?action=AttachFile&do=get&target=wubi-123.png

if I choose C drive for installation drive like shown in the picture, does it format my C drive?

And I'm running Windows 7 Home Premium x64 English SP1 now, does it matter if I choose Japanese for language?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wubi doesn't format anything, it installs as a program in windows, then when your computer boots up it'll let you choose ubuntu or windows, it leaves your C drive alone. Hope I helped.

EDIT: Nor does it matter the language you choose, even if it auto detects it, you can change your language in ubuntu.

Comment: Thanks for the timely answer. What about that uninstallation - do I just simply remove the program in Control Panel -> Programs and Features?

Comment: Yes to remove Ubutnu boot Windows and do what you said.